# Completing second leg of travel on a different day

Tags: air-travel, stopovers

Has anyone had experience booking a flight through a middle city (B) that costs less than a flight from (A) to (C), or from (A) to (B) + (B) to (C), and then interrupted the flight midstream, asking the airline for permission to complete the full journal one of two days later?  Will this be a problem?

Comment: A short layover of one or two days is very common, particularly for long-haul flights. Last time I flew from Auckand to Paris, I stopped in Tokyo on the way there for two days, and Shanghai on the way back for a day. It's unclear what you mean by "interrupted the flight midstream", as any change to your ticket will simply incur the normal change fees imposed by your airline.

Comment: Do you have experience with this traveling on domestic flights?

Answer (score 2):

I do this a lot, and the answer is, it depends!

When pricing any international ticket you may take a break of 23 hours and 59 minutes at any connecting city before it counts as a stopover.* As such if you spend 23 hours at B you are still, from the pricing perspective, "connecting" between A and C. You would be free to leave the airport at this time, subject to any visa requirements.

(When pricing wholly domestic tickets the time is usually reduced to about four or five hours, but there is no hard and fast rule in this case.)

However, you must arrange this at the time of ticketing. Simply put, cheap air fares are not changeable. You cannot expect to walk up to the ticketing desk and achieve this on the day.

Now, if you want a break of longer than 24 hours, this is called a "stopover". Many times, this will trigger an expensive repricing of the ticket. For instance if you were doing New York to Copenhagen via London, introducing a stop in London will often double the price of the ticket. However, many times it will not. If you are travelling on Emirates they are very happy for you to take a free stopover in Dubai.

In general terms, the only way to tell is to feed in your requirements into the pricing engine and see what comes out the other side.

To do this use the "multicity" option and feed in your requirements as A-B, B-C, C-A (or whatever). But one trick you can try is always to see if you can get A-B arriving and B-C departing within 24 hours, because it will often keep the price the same as the A-C/C-A fare.

(* This also applies to fare components that are wholly domestic provided they are included in a ticket that also includes international fare components; but occasionally domestic fares may defeat this presumption by an explicit statement in the Stopovers category.)

Comment: Otherwise +1, but "multicity" fare calculators are very often *not* capable of computing stopovers correctly, and will instead string together absurdly expensive one-ways.  I usually find cheap fares where the conditions allow cheap/free stopovers, then work with a human travel agent to actually book.

Comment: @jpatokal Find a better multicity search! I use matrix.itasoftware.com and then book by phone with the carrier. But if you already have a good TA then great

Comment: Yup, I use ITA Matrix as well, but people unfamiliar with the concept of stopovers probably don't!

Comment: Have you ever done this with domestic travel?  Taken the second flight at a later time?  How does the airline react to the request if it is made between the two flights?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @FrequentWings Yes. I simply price the ticket using the flights at the times I want and then buy the ticket. There's no special procedure.

Comment: @FrequentWings If you ask between the two flights, the airline will treat it as a change after departure. Your ticket will be repriced accordingly. The way that repricing happens is complicated but you should expect it to be quite expensive, similar to buying a walk-up ticket on the same day.

Comment: If I purchase a ticket to go to, say to Dallas from New York, but it goes through Atlanta, what would happen if I asked the airline to continue the leg from Atlanta to Dallas the next day?

Comment: @FrequentWings It depends when you ask. If you ask after you buy the ticket, then the ticket needs to be changed and a change fee + repricing will apply. Just use a multicity tool to arrange it ***before*** you buy anything.

Comment: The 23 hours, 59 minutes rule isn't fixed - and there are exceptions to it. Specifically, if there are no flights from your connecting city to the destination city within that time period.  I once flew from JFK to HRK on Austrian Airlines via VIE.  They only fly from VIE to HRK twice a week and in my case between the time I landed in VIE to the next flight to HRK was more than 24 hours.  This did not count as a stopover and was still counted as a layover.  Moreover the airline paid for my hotel in VIE :)